# How to create a cms pages route in rails 4 application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, content-management-system, routes

I have a CMS engine that I created and I've linked it into my main site and now I'm trying to get it to route to `/about` instead of `/1`, which maps to the CMS Engines pages controllers show action.

```
example pages setup
id | name    | title      | body
1  | about   | About Us   | this is the about page
2  | contact | Contact Us | this is the contact page
```

It will successfully route to `/1` or `/2`

Here is my `routes.rb` of the main application, which loads the cms engine

```
  mount Cms::Engine, :at => '/cms', :as =>'cms'
  mount Blog::Engine, :at => '/blog', :as => 'blog'

  # route to cms pages
  match ":id", :to => 'cms/pages#show', :via => [:get, :post]
```

Here is the show action of the CMS pages controller

```
# GET /pages/1  or GET /pages/name
def show
  begin
     @page = Page.find_by_name(params[:id]) 
     @page ||= Page.find(params[:id]) 
  rescue
    redirect_to "/404.html"
  end
end
```

No matter what I try I can't get it to route the pages to `/name` so `/about` or `/contact`, instead I get an error that reads: `Couldn't find Cms::Page with id=about` or `Couldn't find Cms::Page with id=contact`, but if I go to `/1` or `/2`, then the page is rendered.

My rake routes are:

```
Prefix Verb     URI Pattern    Controller#Action
 cms          /cms           Cms::Engine
blog          /blog          Blog::Engine
     GET|POST /:id(.:format) cms/pages#show

Routes for Cms::Engine:
    pages GET    /pages(.:format)          cms/pages#index
          POST   /pages(.:format)          cms/pages#create
 new_page GET    /pages/new(.:format)      cms/pages#new
edit_page GET    /pages/:id/edit(.:format) cms/pages#edit
     page GET    /pages/:id(.:format)      cms/pages#show
          PATCH  /pages/:id(.:format)      cms/pages#update
          PUT    /pages/:id(.:format)      cms/pages#update
          DELETE /pages/:id(.:format)      cms/pages#destroy
     root GET    /                         cms/login#index

Routes for Blog::Engine:
root GET / blog/index#index
```

Comment: Have you checked what `params[:id]` is, and tried `Page#find_by_name` manually?

Comment: can you post the result of `rake routes` ? What you're trying to achieve is not very clear, nor are you existing cms routes.

Comment: I have a pages controller in my CMS Engine, on the main site I'm trying to load pages, by their name...so I'm not sure how that is not clear

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I figured this out, basically **show** uses the id by default, so I simply created a display action and now it works.

```
def display
  @page = Page.find_by_name(params[:id])
  render 'public/404.html', :status => 404 if @page.nil?
end
```

Comment: If this fully answers your question, you should mark it as accepted (check mark on the left).

Comment: +1 helped me up-voted your response as user did not accept the answer